# Scala: Class, Object, APP in Eclipse Scala plug in

Tags: scala

In Eclipse plugin, I could create scala Object, APP and class. But what's the difference among these 3. Basically, for object, I implement def main(...), then I could run it. But in class, it seems it is similar to normal Java class, but what's the meaning scala APP, it creates a object which extends APP. What's this meant for?

Comment: I think, in this case, [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/App.html) explains it very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the JVM, the starting point of the application is a **static** method `main(String[] args)`, in some class given to the JVM.

In scala there is no static methods, the equivalent is to put a method in an **object** (as opposed to *class*). Putting your main method in a class will not work, it is the same as not marking the method static in java.

`App` is a helper that allows not to write the main method, and put the code directly in the object body.

```
object MyApp extends App {
  doStuff
}
```

does the same thing as

```
object MyApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {doStuff}
}
```

(arguments can be used in doStuff under the name `args`)

Answer (score 2):

Scala has no static methods, so `public static void main` is not available for classes.
Objects are single entries that better fits the "common to every object of a class" scope. So, oversimplifying things, you can think of Object as a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which "acts as an only-static container" (quote from [Scala for Java Refugees](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-3)). If you think about it, that's the perfect place for a main method, and that's why they are declared there.

The [App](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/App.html) trait just explores the fact that instructions written inside the body of an Object are executed as part of its initialization. It couples this standard behaviour with some [delayed initialization tricks](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/App.scala#L1) to use the body of an object as the main method. So, you can think about it as a short alternative syntax to create a application entry point. It replaced the naive [Application](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Application.html) trait that had a lot of shortcomings.

Which one of the two to use is really a matter of taste, but I tend to stick with the more familiar main method syntax.

Cheers,